# Passing variable based on checkbox to php script upon pressuing submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

I have the following html code in which I am trying to define a variable days and pass it off to an php based code upon pressing submit.  Below is a snippet of my code for the html:

```
<html>

<script>
var days="fiveday";
function forecast_parm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    var  output = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
    if (!x){
        output = "fiveday";
    }
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>

<body>
    <form action="check_proc.php" method="get" target="_blank">
        Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="tenday" onchange="forecast_parm()">
        <p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
        <p id="days"></p>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Create Process"></center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon clicking on the submit button I would like to have the variable days be passed off to the php script check_proc.php.  Here is a snippet of that php script:

```
<?php
    $days = $_GET['days'];
    echo "<br>Day is $days</br>";
<?
```

There are other processes that will use the variable days.  Do you know how to tweak either the initial html code or the php script check_proc.php to get the desired results?  That is that upon submit I should have displayed on the web browser "Day is tenday" if the box is checked and "Day is fiveday" if the box is not checked in the initial html page.

Comment: Odd, all the escaped double-quotes.

Comment: Your paragraph in the form won't be passed as a value upon form submission.  But mycheck will if is checked, and you give it a name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never send 'days' to the php script because after a change you only set the html value of the `<p id="days"></p>` element.
`<p>` elements will not be send.

You need a input element to tell the browser to send data if submit is pressed, so add a hidden field 
`<input type='hidden' id='theRealDays' name='days'/>` in the form.

Next, you need to set the value of the element with the id 'theRealDays' after you click the checkbox, so add: 
`document.getElementById("theRealDays").value = output;` 
after
`document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = output;`

After this step when the form is submitted you can access the value with `$_GET['days'];`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. You send it via AJAX
2. You can use your form but with some modifications

With second one

1. You need to add hidden input field to a form f.e

after `<p id="days"></p>` add `<input id="daysValue" type="hidden" name="days" />`

now you need to write to the hidden filed the value of days

after `document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = output;` add

`var  output = document.getElementById("daysValue").value = output;`

After that when you submit the data it will be written to this hidden field, because method of the form is "GET" it will be added to the URL specified in "action" attribute of the form.

In your php I'd suggest using isset() or array_key_exist() before echoing the variable because it may be empty. You can get the value with `echo $_GET['days'];`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a radio group?

```
<?php

$choice = 10; // Default
$choices = [5, 10];

$checked = function($v) use ($choice) {
    return $v == $choice ? 'checked' : '';
};

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['days']) && in_array($_POST['days'], $choices)) {
        echo 'You chose ' . $_POST['days'] . ' days.';
        exit;
    }
}

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="days" value="5" id="five" <?= $checked(5) ?>>
    <label for="five">5 days</label>
    <input type="radio" name="days" value="10" id="ten" <?= $checked(10) ?>>
    <label for="ten">10 days</label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```